# How can I check that a label has fallen off the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a question about UIKit Dynamics. Let's say I'm designing some interactivity, and when the user taps, I want a label with some text to fall off the screen (at which point, I'll destroy it, and a new label will spawn and fall from the top, snap to center, and when the user taps, that too falls off the screen, and on it goes.)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myLabel: UILabel!
var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    myLabel.text = "Some sample text."
    view.addSubview(myLabel)

    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
    gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [myLabel])
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)

}
```

The code above will spawn a UILabel and make it drop off the screen. I understand how to do all of that. However, I'm at a loss concerning how to determine whether or when the label has fallen completely from view, at which point it is removedFromSuperView, and my new label can spawn and fall from the top.

Should I be using a method to determine if the label is intersecting with the view (like CGRectIntersectsRect() )? Or should I try and check whether the center point of the label is inside the bounds of the screen? I've tried hacking together a solution using both of those options but so far nothing has worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think both of those options could work. Post what you've tried, and what problems you had with those methods.

Comment: `subview.frame.origin.y > parentview.bounds.size.height`

Comment: Have you tried giving the `animator` a delegate and implementing `dynamicAnimatorDidPause`?